# Mercurial Unstage Specific Files from Working Directory

Tags: mercurial

I have an uncommitted changeset. I want to commit some of the changes, but not commit some of the files (like unstaging a file in git). Can this be done in mercurial?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the `-X` option to `hg commit` to exclude certain files.  You can specify it more than once on the command line.  For example,

```
hg commit -X path/to/unwanted/file -X path/to/another/file
```

Answer (score 7):

You can pass a list of files to commit to `hg commit`, e.g. `hg commit -m msg file1 file2 ...`.

Answer (score 4):

Yep! You have two options.

1. Commit just some files.

   If you provide file names as arguments to `hg commit`, only those files will be committed. So if I have the following `hg status`:

   ```
   M foo.txt
   M bar.txt
   ```

   I can run `hg commit foo.txt` to commit just the changes to `foo.txt` and leave the changes in `bar.txt` for a later commit.
2. Use the `record` extension.

   The [Record extension](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/RecordExtension) gives Mercurial behavior to git's index, letting you commit just some patches of your changes (like `git add --patch`). See the docs for more info.